# When would a [[Prototype]] refers to a constructor [[Prototype]]: Constructor

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, prototypal-inheritance

While learning prototypical inheritance, I have seen the prototype referring to Array, Object or empty Function.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdiky.png]

I am new to JavaScript programming (prototypical inheritance world) and when debugging SAPUI5 framework I have noticed the prototype is pointing to a constructor.

[image]

Could you please explain me in which scenario `[[Prototype]]` points to a constructor. Can `[[Prototype]]` point to any other apart from these 4 ( Array, Object, Empty Function and Constructor )?

More Info:
If the function is a constructor function it should have a prototype property at the same level where it displays the `[[Prototype]]`

[Constructor Function Example with prototype property and [[Prototype]]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s747b.png)

[prototype property missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KN9ZP.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *[[prototype]]* can point to *any* object (or `null`). What you're asking though is how that object is displayed in the devtools - see [How does DevTools determine an object's constructor's name?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12944719/1048572) and [Javascript Debugging in Chrome - object name?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24658510/1048572) - which uses the name of the function that constructed the object. It means that the prototype is *an* object or *an* array or *a* function, not actually the global `Object`/`Array`/`Function`. When you define your own classes, it'll be the name of that class, which can be anything. In your exampe, SAPUI5 appears to have defined its class(es) via `function constructor() {}`, which is unusual but doesn't matter.

Comment: If the object is constructed via class constructor then the Dev Tools shows it clearly as class <<class name>> . In my case let's assume that it is created by `function constructor() {}` then why it's prototype property is missing in the Dev Tools.

Comment: Moreover the naming convention for a constructor function is that the name always start with a capital letter.

Comment: "It means that the prototype is an object or an array or a function, not actually the global Object/Array/Function." - not actually the global Object  ???? can you shed more light on this statement

Comment: @Athman "*why it's prototype property is missing in the Dev Tools*" - what makes you think it is missing? And *where* exactly did you expect to see it?

Comment: @Athman "*the naming convention for a constructor function is that the name always start with a capital letter.*" - yes, yes it is. I don't know what SAPUI5 `Controller.extend` does (is their code public?) or why it doesn't follow the naming convention. But probably it's a meta variable whose name was never meant to leak.

Comment: "*not actually the global Object?*" - I mean that `Object.getPrototypeOf(b) === Object` is false. Its [[prototype]] is `Object.protototype`, which shows in the console as "an Object".

Comment: thanks for taking time to help me out.
"why it's prototype property is missing in the Dev Tools" - what makes you think it is missing? - Added screen shots in the orginal question under more info

Comment: SAPUI5 Controller.extend does (is their code public?) - https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/base/Metadata.js (line number 480)
Controller - https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller.js

Comment: Ah it looks like the name "constructor" comes from [this line](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/7dd488febc8fc0bab2498f11a1fb97007a166682/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller.js#L64) which is the best bet for the devtools to choose the name of the function and subsequently the class. It can't know it's not a good name :-)

Comment: Regarding the "missing property", you're comparing apples and oranges here. One screenshot shows the *class* object itself (`Person` function object, which has a `Person.prototype` property), the other shows an *instance*. The instance inherits from `DemoControllerApp.prototype`. If you were to log the `DemoControllerApp` class itself you'd see the same as in your first screenshot. But this has nothing to do with [[prototype]], if you need further clarification I'd suggest you [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) about it.

Comment: It is so weird that devtools to choose the name constructor. I tried to create a constructor function named constructor and when i console.dir i am not getting its instance's  `[[Prototype]]`: constructor in the devtools.

Comment: "missing property" - Yeah, my bad. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: The name after the [[prototype]] of an instance is the name of the parent class - in [this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bcDS.png), the `new Person` has `Person.prototype` as its [[prototype]] which is "a `constructor` instance".

Answer (score -2):

`constructor` is just the name of the function that generated the object. The `Array` object's constructor happens to be named `Array` because Javascript's inheritance model was prototypical, historically. Most Javascript builtins will follow this pattern.

Objects from classes implemented in the modern ES6 `class` based notation will have a constructor that is actually named `constructor`.

Comment: "*have a constructor that is actually named `constructor`.*" - no, the constructor's `.name` is the name of the class itself

Comment: "*Javascript's inheritance model was prototypical, historically*" - it still is?!